# Resample groups of rows based on a grouping variable in R

Tags: r, random

I am relatively new to R so apologies if this is a silly / obvious question!  I am interested in creating a new data set that is composed of collections of rows resampled with replacement from a larger data set.

The data set I have looks something like this, multiple rows per grouping variable.

```
> df <- data.frame(value=c(1:5,1:4,1:3),ID=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,4),rep(3,3)))
> df
   value ID
1      1  1
2      2  1
3      3  1
4      4  1
5      5  1
6      1  2
7      2  2
8      3  2
9      4  2
10     1  3
11     2  3
12     3  3
```

What I'd like to do is create a new data set that is resampled (with replacement) based on the grouping variable.  So a resampled data set might look something like this:

```
   value ID
1      1  1
2      2  1
3      3  1
4      4  1
5      5  1
6      1  3
7      2  3
8      3  3
9      1  1
10     2  1
11     3  1
12     4  1
13     5  1
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Do you need `df[sample(nrow(df)), ]` ?

Comment: @RonakShah, thanks for the suggestion.  I'm needing it to take all the rows when a given ID is sampled (i.e., sampling chunks of rows).

Comment: If I understand your question right, using library `dplyr` and grouping, you can try something like this: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(sample(n(), 3, replace = TRUE))`. This works with fixed number to sample. Otherwise, you need to write a loop with `rbind`.

Comment: Thanks, @Gopala. As in the example, the number of rows does vary by the grouping ID.  Any tips on what the loop with rbind might look like?

Comment: See below....three different solutions to achieve what I hope is your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

For sampling different number of rows per ID value, you can try something like this (assuming the ID value has a small number of unique values):

```
result <- NULL
result <- rbind(result, df[sample(row.names(df[df$ID == 1, ]), 10, replace = TRUE), ])
result <- rbind(result, df[sample(row.names(df[df$ID == 2, ]), 5, replace = TRUE), ])
result <- rbind(result, df[sample(row.names(df[df$ID == 3, ]), 3, replace = TRUE), ])
row.names(result) <- seq(1:nrow(result))
```

If there are many ID values, you may want to use a loop with the number of samples for each ID value you desire. For example, if there are six ID values and the corresponding numbers of samples for each ID are 10, 5, 3, 7, 8 and 2, you can do something like this:

```
nsamples <- c(10, 5, 3, 7, 8, 2)
result <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(nsamples)) {
  result <- rbind(result, df[sample(row.names(df[df$ID == i, ]), nsamples[i], replace = TRUE), ])
}
row.names(result) <- seq(1:nrow(result))
```

In either case, you will end up with output like this:

```
   value ID
1      1  1
2      4  1
3      1  1
4      4  1
5      2  1
6      3  1
7      1  1
8      1  1
9      4  1
10     2  1
11     2  2
12     3  2
13     1  2
14     3  2
15     1  2
16     3  3
17     2  3
18     1  3
```

Using the above suggested dplyr solution, you can also do something like this for variable number of samples per ID value (it also requires pre-specifying number of samples per corresponding ID in a vector):

```
library(dplyr)
nsamples <- c(10, 5, 3)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(sample(n(), nsamples[ID], replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: This doesn't successfully do what was asked. It samples a random subset of rows for a given ID. The question asked how to sample IDs with replacement, each time taking all rows with that ID.